# SFB file lost Y-Axis value after it got generated from FBX file in ArCore Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality

I converted FBX file to SFB in Android Studio. When I placed the model using Sceneform the model is placing at position Y-Axis 0 but the in actual FBX file model is showing at some height from surface (having some value for Y-Axis).

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into your SFA file and remove the recenter: 'root' line. This is the default and will put your model on the ground. (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/sfa)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for SFB generated from FBX file. Though, recenter=false worked perfect but the file was OBJ in this case.